# Wildfly Undertow HTTP Response 200 but no content

Tags: httpresponse, wildfly, undertow

I am developing a simple web service using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers : Version: Kepler Service Release 2 Build id: 20140224-0627 and Wildfly-8.2.0.Final. I chose wildfly-javaee7-webapp-blank-archetype using Maven and started development. Firstly, there was no problem, I could add some simple jsp pages and also a simple html page with some images and javascript inclusion then I could deployed, launched and accessed those pages by browser. But all of a sudden, Wildfly (I guess Undertow maybe?) started to response with HTTP response 200 with no content... I really don't get what is going on. I also did rollback my sources to the very early simple pages only. But still the symptoms are the same. Also I have tried to use newer version of Wildfly-9.0.1.Final and  deployed manually but I haven't seen any difference.

ex1) this is ok. (Of course browsers take care of this...)

ex2) this kind of contents won't be loaded and sent back as content 0...

I doubted local path issue but I haven't changed anything and it was loaded earlier.

It would be really appreciated if somebody could give me a solution.

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly couldn't put the code.

ex1) this is ok. (Of course browsers take care of this...) 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

ex2) this kind of contents won't be loaded and sent back as content 0...

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have solved this problem. I have found a problem on a servlet I have added at last. Actually I was trying to migrate my web service running on glassfish and did migrate files one by one. I specified a URL to be handled by the servlet in Web.xml when it run on glassfish. But somehow, it's not working on Wildfly which means all URL request are unexpectedly handled by the servlet... Since I have no idea to specify url to be handled by the specific servlet in Web.xml for Wildfly, I decided to filter request URL in the servlet code. So it is working now. Thank you guys trying to help me...